# progress openedge 11.4 issue with table names

Tags: openedge, cognos-10, progress-db

we are using progress openegde 11.4 database and ibm cognos10.2, when we are importing tables (consist of underscore(_) like Emp_Info) from progress to cognos frameworkmanager tool to create the model, it is giving the below error

```
[DataDirect].[ODBC Progress openedge wire protocol driver].[OPENEDGE]Syntax Error in sql statement at or about "Emp_Info" AND Sysprogress.sysindexes(10713)
```

If we don't have any underscore in the table names,it is working fine...

Please give the suggestions to solve this issue.

Comment: Is it possible to see the query? I cannot imagine why Sysprogress.sysindexes is seen in error message. Are you doing something with indexes?

Answer (score 0):

I would use and ODBC trace in the Windows ODBC administrator tool to trace the calls to and from the driver if Cognos FM is passing the incorrect call to the driver, or if the ODBC client is passing the incorrect SQL to the database based on the FM request.

Most likely this is a defect related to the driver and I would recommend contacting the provider of the driver first. Preferably with the trace in hand. This suggestion is based on that IBM Cognos will not have any idea on what the name of the views to find the tables names in the database are, since all major versions of databases use different table names. Cognos BI would likely use a [generic call similar to this one.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms711683(v=vs.85).aspx)

I'd suggest this is probably a programming error.

Answer (score -1):

Are you quoting the table names?  I.e.

Select * from "emp_info"

Comment: Thanks for ur reply tom. Not quoted, it is not possible to edit query before importing the tables in cognos. actualy we are directly importing tables to cognos framework manager using odbc dsn by selecting the table names